# Elastic search throws errror while running upgrade command via CLI in magento 2

Tags: elasticsearch, magento2.4.2, magento-cloud

I have successfully cloned & installed a Magento cloud environment Magento 2.4.2 in my local instance.

And also installed elastic search and tested it via the command line and it's working fine.

Note: I have followed his link to install and configure elastic search https://www.emizentech.com/blog/magento-2-4-with-elasticsearch-complete-guide.html

Output from the command line:
[image]

But while running upgrade command throws following error.

[image]

Elastic search configuration file

/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml

[image]

Can anyone please help me to sort out this?

Comment: systemctl enable elasticsearch.service 
 and sudo systemctl start elasticsearch.service and https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/starting-elasticsearch.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just restart the service :)

```
sudo systemctl stop elasticsearch
sudo systemctl start elasticsearch
```

You may also need to execute:

```
sudo systemctl enable elasticsearch
```